# Which thread is used for execution of Flutter's MethodChannel on Native side?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

When i call invokeMapMethod/invoke...Method from a Flutter side to execute some callback on C++ side from an Isolate, is the Native code also executed in this isolate? Or i have to create an additional thread(if we are talking about Windows methodchannel) to avoid UI thread blocking?

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests it's running in the default UI isolate so if you want to execute some performant task you should create a separate thead